# ionic -firebase email& password login not working in android

Tags: android, angularjs, firebase

It's work OK in web browser but when I try to login via email& password I get the error :

> Unable to contact the Firebase server

this is how I login :

```
 var auth = $firebaseAuth(firebaseMainRef);

            auth.$authWithPassword({  email    : email,    password : password  })
```

I use: `Firebase v2.0.5`

this is the `confif.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.myapp501948" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>myApp</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
</widget>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding cordova plugin of whitelist solves the problem